# How to reset remote master back to a commit which has not been merged with another branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

The scenario is as follows:

1. at commit 001 on master branch, create branch b1
2. make multiple commit to b1
3. merge the HEAD of b1 with master branch
4. Figure out it is a mistake to merge. So I'd like to revert back to commit 001 on remote master branch. Then I could start a pull request between master and b1 branch.

Based on the above description, Which command should I use to revert the remote master branch back to commit 001?

Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have pushed the merged master to the remote repo and you are not allowed to rewrite the published history,

```
git checkout master
git revert <merge_commit> -m 1
git push origin master
```

If you haven't,

```
git checkout master
git reset <001> --hard
```

If you are allowed to rewrite the remote history,

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! After I doing so, I intend to start a pull request between master and b1, it says on github that there's nothing to compare. Why is that?

Comment: ```git checkout master; git log; git revert -m 1 <merge-commit>; 
git push -u origin master```

Comment: @Judking sorry, culpa mea. I should have asked you for more details. Was it a true merge or a fast-forward merge? If it's a fast-forward merge, use `git reset <001> --hard` and `git push -f origin master` to update the remote master by force.

Comment: Actually, I don't have -f permissions on master branch. And what I did before is ```git checkout master;
git pull origin master;
git merge test;
git push origin master;```

Comment: @Judking was it a fast-forward merge or not? If yes, git revert every commit introduced by b1. If no, git revert the merge commit -m 1 should work.

Comment: @Judking I cannot access to Github right now. Is it possible to launch a pull request between 001 and b1 on Github?

Comment: Nope, it says there's nothing to compare between master and b1 now.